# replies are not going to custom email address specified in Sender profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

My email campaign has replies as the CTA but I want replies going to a custom email address specified in the sender profile below

[image]

The Auto reply **RMM response** works when you reply to this email but the email is not sent to Custom@email.com

What am i doing wrong.

Below is the RMM page.

**Reply sub domain** is the verified SAP which is used in the **Email Reply Address**

**The Routing address for remaining replies** at the bottom is a second custom email.

[image]